# How to calculate a point on a circle knowing the radius and center point

Tags: math, geometry

I have a complicated problem and it involves an understanding of Maths I'm not confident with.

Some slight context may help. I'm building a 3D train simulator for children and it will run in the browser using WebGL. I'm trying to create a network of points to place the track assets (see image) and provide reference for the train to move along.

To help explain my problem I have created a visual representation as I am a designer who can script and not really a programmer or a mathematician:

[image: visualisation of problem]

Basically, I have 3 shapes (Figs. A, B & C) and although they have width, can be represented as a straight line for A and curves (B & C). Curves B & C are derived (bend modified) from A so are all the same length (l) which is 112. The curves (B & C) each have a radius (r) of 285.5 and the (a) angle they were bent at was 22.5°.

Each shape (A, B & C) has a registration point (start point) illustrated by the centre of the green boxes attached to each of them.

What I am trying to do is create a network of "track" starting at 0, 0 (using standard Cartesian coordinates).

My problem is where to place the next element after a curve. If it were straight track then there is no problem as I can use the length as a constant offset along the y axis but that would be boring so I need to add curves.

Fig. D. demonstrates an example of a possible track layout but please understand that I am not looking for a static answer (based on where everything is positioned in the image), I need a formula that can be applied no matter how I configure the track.

Using Fig. D. I tried to work out where to place the second curved element after the first one. I used the formula for plotting a point of the circumference of a circle given its centre coordinates and radius (Fig. E.).

I had point 1 as that was simply a case of setting the length (y position) of the straight line. I could easily work out the centre of the circle because that's just the offset y position, the offset of the radius (r) (x position) and the angle (a) which is always 22.5° (which, incidentally, was converted to Radians as per formula requirements).

After passing the values through the formula I didn't get the correct result because the formula assumed I was working anti-clockwise starting at 3 o'clock so I had to deduct 180 from (a) and convert that to Radians to get the expected result.

That did work and if I wanted to create a 180° track curve I could use the same centre point and simply deducted 22.5° from the angle each time. Great. But I want a more dynamic track layout like in Figs. D & E.

So, how would I go about working point 5 in Fig. E. because that represents the centre point for that curve segment? I simply have no idea.

Also, as a bonus question, is this the correct way to be doing this or am I over-complicating things?

This problem is the only issue stopping me from building my game and, as you can appreciate, it is a bit of a biggie so I thank anyone for their contribution in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like you're overcomplicating things.  You might want to look in to splines.  This is a mathematical technique where you split a long path in to several smaller functions.  So in this example, you wouldn't deal with circles.  You would take the straight path from the origin.  Then, you would travel along a curved path defined by a functions (not this segment of a circle stuff, which is just going to be a headache).  Each segment starts where the previous one left off, and the curvature of each segment should be self contained.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you build up the track, the position of the next piece of track to be placed needs to be relative to location and direction of the current end of the track.

I would store an (`x`,`y`) position and an angle `a` to indicate the current point (with `x`,`y` starting at 0, and `a` starting at pi/2 radians, which corresponds to straight up in the "anticlockwise from 3-o'clock" system).

Then construct

```
fx = cos(a);
fy = sin(a);
lx = -sin(a);
ly = cos(a);
```

which correspond to the x and y components of 'forward' and 'left' vectors relative to the direction we are currently facing. If we wanted to move our position one unit forward, we would increment (x,y) by (fx, fy).

In your case, the rule for placing a straight section of track is then:

```
x=x+112*fx
y=y+112*fy
```

The rule for placing a curve is slightly more complex. For a curve turning right, we need to move forward 112*sin(22.5°), then side-step right 112*(1-cos(22.5°), then turn clockwise by 22.5°. In code,

```
x=x+285.206*sin(22.5*pi/180)*fx // Move forward
y=y+285.206*sin(22.5*pi/180)*fy

x=x+285.206*(1-cos(22.5*pi/180))*(-lx) // Side-step right
y=y+285.206*(1-cos(22.5*pi/180))*(-ly)

a=a-22.5*pi/180 // Turn to face new direction
```

Turning left is just like turning right, but with a negative angle.

To place the subsequent pieces, just run this procedure again, calculating `fx`,`fy`, `lx` and `ly` with the now-updated value of `a`, and then incrementing `x` and `y` depending on what type of track piece is next.

There is one other point that you might consider; in my experience, building tracks which form closed loops with these sort of pieces usually works if you stick to making 90° turns or rather symmetric layouts. However, it's quite easy to make tracks which don't quite join up, and it's not obvious to see how they should be modified to allow them to join. Something to bear in mind perhaps if your program allows children to design their own layouts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and detailed explanation. I did think there may be a simpler way and would have eventually got there as I've already simplified a few parts of this using trigonometric functions but will give your suggestion a try and get back to you. Incidentally, the routes of the tracks will be designed by myself as I will build a track editor and they're going to be pretty much non-looping routes (with the exception of small loop lines which will branch off a main line. Thanks so much again, going to implement this later this evening.

Comment: I got more or less the same formula (just too slow ... :-) . - One remark: If `l = 112` and `a = 22.5°`, then the radius is `r = l * 180/(22.5 * π) = l * 8 / π ≈ 285.206`, not `r = 285.5`.

Comment: Thanks - I was too lazy to check the number in the original post!

Comment: Tried a dummy of your code suggestion (I'm using JavaScript) and the 'straight' code produces expected results but the curve result for X seems off. Have a look here  http://frontier.lincoln.ac.uk/3d/development/Stage3/Trains/points_formula3.html  the code is in <pre> tag but also runs if you have a browser that has a debug console. The first turn yields a X value of 506.3496110111178 when it should be more around the 220 region. Could you see if there's anything I've got wrong? Appreciate it.

Comment: @jayfield1979 Ah, I see that I had some unmatched brackets in my answer, and your code matches them in a way other than the way I intended... You need (1-cos(angle))*(-lx) rather than (1-cos(angle)*(-lx)). Now fixed in the answer

Comment: @jayfield1979 Actually I think there may be a further bug; what I called a 'left' vector is actually a 'right' vector. To fix, change -lx(a) to lx(a) where it occurs, or increment a rather than decrementing it.

Comment: @Chris Johnson if you have time, there is a follow up question that I'd appreciate your help with :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384217/how-to-find-points-on-the-circumference-of-a-arc-knowing-a-start-point-an-end-p

Answer (score 0):

Point 5 is equidistant from 3 as 2, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: In the static example I posted (track configuration A B C) then yes, but my track layout will vary. Although that has given me an idea. I will get back to you.