# How to find points on the circumference of a arc knowing a start point, an end point and the radius?

Tags: math, geometry

Please see the image below for a visual clue to my problem:

[image: Problem]

I have the coordinates for points 1 and 2. They were derived by a formula that uses the other information available (see question: [How to calculate a point on a circle knowing the radius and center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359823/how-to-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-knowing-the-radius-and-center-point)).

What I need to do now (separately from the track construction) is plot the points in green between point 1 and 2.

What is the best way of doing so? My Maths skills are not the best I have to admit and I'm sure there's a really simple formula I just can't work out (from my research) which to use or how to implement.

Comment: Given point 1, the radius and `a`, could you plot point 2?

Comment: what are the coordinates of 1, 2 and the centre?

Comment: 0,112 ... etc just saw other question

Comment: Two questions: Is the `r` line always horizontal? Does the dotted line connected to point 2 also have length `r`?

Comment: @Kevin: I can answer the second question: yes, that's what "radius" means.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I'm not looking for a 'static' solution in that points 1 and 2 could be any set of coordinates generated from the formula in the linked post hence why I removed them from this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the notation of my answer to your linked question (i.e. x,y is the current location, fx,fy is the current 'forward vector', and lx,ly is the current 'left vector')

```
for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
  sub_angle=(i/10)*deg2rad(22.5);
  xi=x+285.206*(sin(sub_angle)*fx + (1-cos(sub_angle))*(-lx))
  yi=y+285.206*(sin(sub_angle)*fy + (1-cos(sub_angle))*(-ly))
  // now plot green point at (xi, yi)
}
```

would generate eleven green points equally spaced along the arc.

Comment: As with your previous post you've been a massive help Chris. That's just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: it works well but how would I work out the new rotation to go with the new X and Y coordinates?

Comment: ahhh got it: ai = a + sub_angle

Answer (score 4):

The equation of a circle with center (h,k) and radius r is

(x - h)² + (y - k)² = r² if that helps

check out this link for points http://www.analyzemath.com/Calculators/CircleInterCalc.html

The parametric equation for a circle is

x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
Where r is the radius, cx,cy the origin, and a the angle from 0..2PI radians or 0..360 degrees.

Comment: Due to the formula used to the generate the points (1 and 2 in this example) I do not know the centre point of these curves. Each curves position is relative to the previous piece of track which could be a curve or a straight. I suppose the centre point would be worked out but was hoping for a solution without resorting to too many calculations.