# How to calculate points y position on arc? When i have radius, arcs starting and ending points

Tags: geometry, automatic-ref-counting, cnc

I'm trying to write a program on CNC. Basically I have circular arc starting x, y , radius and finishing x, y also I know the direction of the arc clockwise or cc. So I need to find out the value of y on the arc at the specific x position. What is the best way to do that?
I found similar problem on this website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384217/how-to-find-points-on-the-circumference-of-a-arc-knowing-a-start-point-an-end-p). But i not sure how to get angle a.

[image: sample]

Comment: Do you just want y_random or do you want the angle as well?

Comment: x=R cos(theta), so theta = arccos(x/R), y=R sin(theta). You may need to may need to make sure you are in the correct quadrant.

Comment: sorry, i haven't mention this but its circular arc.

Comment: francium i just want to get y_random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have to find circle equation. Let's start point `Pst = (xs,ys)`, end point `Pend = (xend,yend)`

For simplicity shift all coordinates by `(-xs, -ys)`, so start point becomes coordinate origin.

New `Pend' = (xend-xs,yend-ys) = (xe, ye)`, new 'random point' coordinate is `xr' = xrandom - xs`, unknown circle center is `(xc, yc)`

```
xc^2 + yc^2 = R^2    {1}
(xc - xe)^2 + (yc-ye)^2 = R^2  {2}  //open the brackets
xc^2 - 2*xc*xe + xe^2 + yc^2 - 2*yc*ye + ye^2 = R^2    {2'}
subtract {2'} from {1}
2*xc*xe - xe^2  + 2*yc*ye - ye^2 = 0    {3}
yc =  (xe^2 + ye^2 - 2*xc*xe) / (2*ye) {4}
substitute {4} in {1}
xc^2 + (xe^2 + ye^2 - 2*xc*xe)^2 / (4*ye^2) = R^2 {5}
solve quadratic equation {5} for xc, choose right root (corresponding to arc direction), find yc

having center coordinates (xc, yc), write
yr' = yc +- Sqrt(R^2 -(xc-xr')^2) //choose right sign if root exists
and finally exclude coordinate shift
yrandom = yr' + ys
```

Answer (score 0):

equation of a circle is `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`

in your case, we know `x_random` and `R`

substituting in knows we get,

```
x_random ^ 2 + y_random ^ 2 = R ^ 2
```

and solving for `y_random` get get

```
y_random = sqrt( R ^ 2 - x_random ^ 2 )
```

Now we have `y_random`

Edit: this will only work if your arc is a circular arc and not an elliptical arc

to adapt this answer to an ellipse, you'll need to use this equation, instead of the equation of a circle

`( x ^ 2 / a ^ 2 ) + ( y ^ 2 / b ^ 2 )  = 1`, where `a` is the radius along the `x axis` and `b` is the radius along `y axis`

---

Simple script to read data from a file called `data.txt` and compute a series of `y_random` values and write them to a file called `out.txt`

```
import math                                                                 

def fromFile():                                                             
    fileIn = open('data.txt', 'r')                                          
    output = ''                                                             
    for line in fileIn:                                                     
        data = line.split()                                                 
        # line of data should be in the following format                    
        # x h k r                                                           
        x = float(data[0])                                                  
        h = float(data[1])                                                  
        k = float(data[2])                                                  
        r = float(data[3])                                                  
        y = math.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)+k                                    
        if ('\n' in line):                                                  
            output += line[:-1] + ' | y = ' + str(y) + '\n'                 
        else:                                                               
            output += line + ' | y = ' + str(y)                             
    print(output)                                                           
    fileOut = open('out.txt', 'w')                                          
    fileOut.write(output)                                                   
    fileIn.close()                                                          
    fileOut.close()                                                         

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                  
    fromFile()
```

`data.txt` should be formatted as such

```
x0 h0 k0 r0
x1 h1 k1 r1
x2 h2 k2 r2
... for as many lines as required
```

Comment: i thought equation for circle is (x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2. Am i wrong? h, k centre of a circle.

Comment: @aidas h and k are used to translate the circle along the x and y axis. If you don't translate the circle, h=0, k=0, then you get x^2 + y^2 = r^2

Comment: but in my case h and k isn't 0. i could offset origin to zero with every arc in the program i'm making. but i'm hoping that there's cleaner method.

Comment: @aidas well for every arc the calculation is still the same, only difference is the numbers you plug in. You could easily write a simple program (python for example) that will accept your numbers and quickly compute the result.

Comment: @fracium could you show me how its done? python is fine. just centre of circle is unknown. i found equation for it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/how-to-find-center-of-an-arc-given-start-point-end-point-radius-and-arc-direc). its just my math skills to solve this one isn't good enough.

Comment: @aidas, I updated the answer to include a python script